# Allow widget to be pushed off the screen by content below when the keyboard is opened

Tags: flutter, user-interface

What I'm trying to do is have an image widget at the top of the screen then have some inputs and a button at the bottom for logging in like so:

[image]

And then when the user opens the keyboard I want the inputs to stick to the bottom of screen being pushed up by the keyboard which is pretty easy to do on a large device but on smaller devices the inputs hit the image and get covered by the keyboard causing errors so instead I want to have the image simply pushed upwards and off the screen by the inputs but I can't figure out how to do it so far I've managed to get this:

[image]

Which is obviously not quite what I'm after as I don't want the image to shrink I just want it to be pushed off the screen any suggestions would be much appreciated

Minimal code to get the results shown in the images

```dart
return Stack(
  children: [
    Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Flexible(
            child: Container(child: Image.asset('assets/temp.png', height: 115)),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                50, 0, 50, isKeyboardVisible ? 10 : 50),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.grey[350],
                    hintText: 'Username',
                    contentPadding:
                        EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                TextFormField(
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.grey[350],
                    hintText: 'Password',
                    contentPadding:
                        EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                Center(
                  child: Material(
                    elevation: 5.0,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    color: Colors.lightGreen,
                    child: MaterialButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text(
                        'Login',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

**EDIT:** So I've been playing around for a little while and I've managed to get further but now all the way this is the code I have now:

```dart
return Stack(
  children: [
    Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
              MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom, // screen height minus keyboard height but interestingly if i just do MediaQuery.of(context).size.height i dont get errors so its almost working
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Image.asset('assets/temp.png', height: 115),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                    50, 0, 50, isKeyboardVisible ? 10 : 50),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextFormField(
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.grey[350],
                        hintText: 'Username',
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                            20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    TextFormField(
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.grey[350],
                        hintText: 'Password',
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                            20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    Center(
                      child: Material(
                        elevation: 5.0,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        color: Colors.lightGreen,
                        child: MaterialButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text(
                            'Login',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

As you can see in the comment thats in the code I'm taking the screen height then taking the keyboard height away as it then shrinks the Columns pushing the inputs up but I get errors however if I don't take the keyboard height away it almost works but there is a massive gap between the image and the inputs which is not what I want hence why I'm removing the keyboard height but then that causes issues so I can't figure out what I'm supposed to do to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

remove Flexible and then
try wrapping your column with  `SingleChildScrollView`

```
Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(child:Column(
```

Comment: This causes an error:

RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the vertical direction.
These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.

Comment: just remove the Flexible Since its child has static height

Comment: that then results in the input boxes no longer being at the bottom defeating what I'm trying to do its difficult to figure out what would work

Comment: increase the height from 115 to something like `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*.5`